# how can i pass parameters to crystal report using access database?

Tags: c#

this is my code

```
if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    int invoiceid = Convert.ToInt32(txtSellId.Text)-1;
    RPT.RPTPrintSellBill myreport = new RPT.RPTPrintSellBill();
    myreport.SetParameterValue("@SaleId", invoiceid);
    RPT.RptSellBill frm = new RPT.RptSellBill();
    frm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myreport;
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

this is my databsase access query

```
SELECT SalePill.SaleId, Customer.customerName, SalePill.SaleTotalG, SalePill.SaleTotalS, SalePill.SaleItemCount, SalePill.SaleAdd, SalePill.SaleDiscount, SalePill.SaleFinalTotal, Operation.saleQty, Operation.sellUnitPrice, Operation.saleTotaG, Operation.saleDiscount, Operation.saleTotalB, Stock.StockName, Items.itemName, SalePill.SaleCustomer, SalePill.SaleDate, SalePill.SaleInvoiceNo, SalePill.SaleUser FROM Stock INNER JOIN ((Customer INNER JOIN (Items INNER JOIN (Operation INNER JOIN SalePill ON Operation.saleId = SalePill.SaleId) ON Items.itemId = Operation.operItem) ON Customer.customersId = SalePill.SaleCustomer) INNER JOIN StockItems ON Operation.stockId = StockItems.stockId) ON Stock.StockId = StockItems.stockId;
```

i need my report to show only one invoice by passing the invoice id

this what happened when i use my code

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and what happened?

Comment: i edited my question sorry for that  ...

Comment: [check your parameter names](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/226633/Crystal-Report-Invalid-index-Exception-from-HRESUL?tab=mostrecent)